# Copy bytes of String to chosen array in chosen charset

Tags: java, arrays, string, character-encoding, java-8

In Java 1.8.0, I would like to have the bytes of a String copied to a given array without a new array being returned. I have found three methods which approximate what I would like:

1. `byte[] String.getBytes(String charsetName)` gives the result I would like, but it returns a new array.
2. `void String.getBytes(int srcBegin, int srcEnd, byte dst[], int dstBegin)` copies to a given array, but it has no option for choosing the charset, dropping the upper 8 bits of each `char` in `char[] String.value`. This method also happens to be deprecated.
3. `byte[] StringCoding.encode(Charset cs, char[] ca, int off, int len)`, which is called by the above `String.getBytes`, also does the job, but it returns a new array. This method also happens not to be publicly usable.

My use case is iterating over a collection of strings, reading their bytes into an existing structure which does not care about having a unique byte array for every string. One-time allocation of objects at the beginning is okay, but I do not want to allocate objects while iterating over the strings.

Could anyone suggest how I could have the functionality of the second method without the allocation of a new array or any other object?

Comment: The second method is @Deprecated and should not be used.
The third one is in a package-visible class and could not be used.

So I would use the first method.

Comment: I'm aware of this. I listed the methods to illustrate the functionality I'd like. The first method returns a new array, which is not what I want.

Comment: Maybe you should mention why you want to do it that way and what you want to achieve. Sometimes a different approach might fit better to the goal.

Comment: I've now added my reason.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your array in a ByteBuffer, and use a CharsetEncoder directly:

```
byte[] byteArray = ...;
String charsetName = ...;

ByteBuffer buffer =
    ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray, dstBegin, dstEnd - dstBegin);
CharsetEncoder encoder = Charset.forName(charsetName).newEncoder();
CoderResult result =
    encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(string), buffer, true);
if (!result.isUnderflow()) {
    result.throwException();
}
```

Note that [ByteBuffer.wrap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#wrap-byte:A-int-int-) is lightweight and does not create a new array;  it just provides a ByteBuffer instance that delegates its storage to the byte array given to the method.

If you plan to use the entire byte array, you can just use the easier-to-read `ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray)`.

Comment: `CharBuffer.wrap(string)` involves the allocation of a new object for every string.

Comment: I've updated the question with a better explanation of my use case.

Comment: I've found a possible solution derived from your original one. First create a `CharBuffer stringCharBuffer = CharBuffer.allocate(capacity)`. Then have a `stringCharBuffer.put(string)` before the `encode` line, and replace `CharBuffer.wrap(string)` with `stringCharBuffer`. If you want to edit your answer with this,  I can accept it.

Comment: You will of course have to iterate through all your Strings and determine the largest length in order to define your `capacity`.  Also, after calling stringCharBuffer.put, you need to call [flip()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#flip--) to properly set the buffer’s position and limit so it can be read by the CharsetEncoder.

Comment: True. I actually don't mind reallocating to double the capacity instead of iterating twice.

Comment: One more consideration:  If you encode Strings of different lengths into the same byte array, how will you know how many bytes in the byte array are actual data?  Charsets like UTF-8 do not use the same number of bytes for every character, so you cannot easily compute the byte count from the String length.  You can solve that problem by using a ByteBuffer rather than a plain byte array.

Comment: I've found a solution using `CharsetEncoder.maxBytesPerChar`. I will make an edit with that solution.

Comment: That will tell you how many bytes to allocate.  It will not tell you how many bytes each encoded String uses.  For instance, "test" uses 4 bytes in UTF-8, while "δοκιμή" uses 24 bytes.

Comment: That is correct. The number of bytes encoded can then be got from the ByteBuffer position after encoding. I was going to post a solution which I converted from my working Scala solution, but there seems to be a slight problem which I couldn't figure out. I'll post it tomorrow morning.

Comment: I proposed an edit along the lines of https://gist.github.com/jpcooper/837a62e422c333bc19ddf0fdd164b355 , but it was rejected as deviating from the original question. Could you suggest what I should do?

Comment: You are free to post an answer (not just a comment) to your own question, even if it’s based on the answers and/or comments of others (as long as it’s not essentially identical to another answer).

Comment: Okay, I'll do that. I just wanted to give you credit for your answer.